# Reading, Comparing and taking input non ASCII charachter(i.e Bangla and other indic script) array in C

Tags: c, non-ascii-characters

Can I work with Begali charachters(non ASCII) in C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. Look into libiconv or ICU.